# ProfilePicture saved in Public directory while user already exists in database

Tags: node.js

### Controller

**I add a checker which check if user already exists then not save any details, but this code save profilepicture in public directory , i want to confirm that no any data save in database if user exists already but image save in public directory**

```js
const addUser = async (req, res) => {
    let validation = ''
    if (!req.body.Username) {
        validation += 'UserName is require'
    }

    if (!req.body.Password) {
        validation += 'Password is require'
    }

    if (!req.body.Email) {
        validation += 'Email is require'
    }

    if (!req.body.Password) {
        validation += 'Password is require'
    }

    if (!!validation) {
        res.send({ success: false, status: 500, message: validation })
    }
    else {
        let totalUser = await User.countDocuments()
        let newUser = new User({
            UserID: totalUser + 1,
            Username: req.body.Username,
            Email: req.body.Email,
            Password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.Password, 10),
            ProfilePicture: req.body.ProfilePicture
        })

        let prevUser = await User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email })
        if (!!prevUser) {
            res.send({ success: false, status: 500, message: 'User Exists with same email' })
        }
        else {
            newUser.save().then(saveduser => {
                res.send({ success: true, status: 200, message: 'user added successfully', data: saveduser })
            }).catch(err=>{
                res.status(500).json({success: false, message: "Error happenned while uploading !", err});
            })
        }
    }
}
```

### Routes

```js
let userStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'server/public/user')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let picname = Date.now() + file.originalname
        req.body.ProfilePicture = 'user/' + picname
        cb(null, picname)
    }
})
const uploadUser = multer({ storage: userStorage })

router.post("/add",uploadUser.single('ProfilePicture'),userController.addUser)
```

```
 i want if user already exits then no any details save in database and public diirectory, this code work good means not save any data in database if user already exits, but ProfilePicture save in Public directory
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue because your `Multer` `middleware` gets called before your actual route `controller` method. Hence when the flow gets to the condition where existing user is being checked the file has already been stored on the server in specified directory.
There can be multiple ways to change that but the two of the easier ones which come to my mid are:

- Either validate the uniqueness of email before `Multer` parses the file
  and saves it. For that you can write another `middleware` where the
  email is matched in the DB, and call the newly written `middleware`
  before `Multer` parser. A trick could be to extract email field from
  the `Multipart FormData`, as the request will not contain a `JSON` body
  before `Multer` `Parser` parses the body and extract files. You can
  search online for how to extract  body parameter from `Multipart FormData` request body.
- Another easy hack would be to manually remove the user profile
  picture file if user already exists. This is a hack and not efficient
  as it will cost extra resources to first save a file and then delete
  it. But it can get the work done. To handle your problem this way you
  can change your controller function in the following way:

```
   /*Existing Code*/

   let prevUser = await User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email })
        if (!!prevUser) {
            //deleting the file for user
            await fs.unlink(req.body.ProfilePicture)
            //It is a conflicting scenario so change the status to 409
            res.send({ success: false, status: 409, message: 'User Exists with same email' })
        }

   /*Existing Code*/
```

NOTE: In above code you can see status code change, you can read more about [HTTP Status Code 409 here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409).